# IE and !important - why isnt it working?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have this CSS:

```
.add-to-cart .button {
    background: url("pic.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent !important;
    height:37px !important;
    width:171px;
}
```

This should set the pic.gif image for a button with class button inside a div with class add-to-cart no matter what was done before. This works in Chrome, FF and Opera, but not in IE9. Any ideas whats wrong with that one?

Thanks!

Comment: What goes wrong? What happens instead of what you expect? Which of the two important styles fails? Also, which rules are you overriding with `!important`?

Comment: IE applies what is done above in the same css file, it seems to ignore the !important.

Comment: Then show more of the css, please. And the HTML. Preferably as a jsFiddle.

Comment: What you can do is try to put the arguments of the background property in the correct order. Color, image, repeat, attachment, position. I don't know if it matters, but I can't test anyway without enough data.

Comment: The rule I am overwriting is 
`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#bbbbbb');` 

Removing this line, makes it work as I want.

Comment: I think you may want to read up on what `!important` does exactly.

Answer (score 0):

try removing transparent from

background: url("pic.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent !important;